# Ejecutar un método dentro de otro en Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola como puedo ejecutar un método dentro de otro en Java, si se que puedo invocarlo cuando es asi prívate void metodo(); lo invoco asi metodo(); per cuando lleva parámetros así prívate void metodo(clase mod); ya no me funciona como puedo hacerlo en ese caso.

Este quiero llamarlo en otro metodo

```
public void mostrar(usuarios mod) {
    Conexion crearSql = new Conexion();
    horarios crear = new horarios();

    SqlUsuarios mosSql = new SqlUsuarios();
    usuarios mos = new usuarios();

    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    ResultSet rs = crearSql.getTabla("SELECT nombre FROM horarios WHERE id_user =" + mod.getId());
    ResultSet rd = crearSql.getTabla("SELECT  COUNT(*) total FROM horarios WHERE id_user =" + mod.getId());
    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Horarios Creados"});

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("nombre")});
        }
        table.setModel(modelo);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerAlight);
        //materialTabbed3.add(modelo, new JPanel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    try {
        while (rd.next()) {
            jLabel4.setText(rd.getString("total"));

        }
        //materialTabbed3.add(modelo, new JPanel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Al llamarlo aquí me aparece un error (usuarios es una clase de otro paquete)

```
//Sobrecarga de metodos
public Tablero(usuarios mod) {
    initComponents();

    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
    table.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(236, 244, 249));
    table.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(132, 139, 140));
    table.setRowHeight(25);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.mod = mod;

    lblnombre.setText(mod.getNombres());
    lblrol.setText(mod.getNombre_tipo());

    jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(mod.getId()));

    if (mod.getId_tipo() == 1) {

    } else if (mod.getId_tipo() == 2) {
        jPanel9.setVisible(false);
        jLabel5_Amigos1.setVisible(false);
    }
```

}

Es lo que tengo en cada método todo esta bien solo quiero llamar el metodo mostrar en Tablero para que mostrar se pueda ejecutar y me muestro los valores en el formulario. asi como esta en el formulario me sale en blanco.

Comment: se llama de la misma forma y se le pasan los parametros, que por algo los esta esperando...

Comment: y por que no puedes pasarle el parámetro que tiene el método Tablero??

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: no no puedo llamarlo en ningún otro lado a menos que le quite (usuarios mod) y quede así ()

Comment: Si podes llamarlo, desde cualquier lado, si le pasas el parametro que requiere... si pusieras codigo en lugar de imagenes, seria mucho mas facil ayudarte ;)

Comment: Listo ya lo edite y agregue al ultimo un comentario mas, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: no se cual queres que llame a cual, pero los dos reciben por parametro un objeto de la clase usuarios, asi que deberias mandarle eso mismo al otro metodo...

Comment: si lo pongo asi mostrar(usuarios mod) en el metodo tablero me sale error

Comment: solo tendrias que poner mostar(mod)

Comment: @Dramaturgo graciassss amigo si solo era de poner mostrar(mod) eso resolvió mi problema.